# Desktop displayed without password after hibernate

Tags: linux, boot, debian, hibernate

OS: Debian 8.7
Kernel: 4.2
DE: Mate 1.8.1

I often use Hibernate on my laptop when switching between OS to save myself time (I have Windows on another partition on the same drive). However I have noticed one strange quirk.

When I boot back into Debian after a Hibernate, the previous contents of my screen at the point where I entered hibernation are displayed in full for a brief moment (about a second). I have not yet been quick enough to test if there is any interactivity available (such as keyboard or mouse).

After that brief moment, I am then presented with the login screen.

I am curious if this would be considered a security issue, as the contents of my screen are displayed without any password entry and I have become conscious of this when setting hibernation to the point of opening a new document in sublime and full-screening it first.

I have a two part question.

- *Should this concern me?*
- *Is there anything I can do about it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the graphics buffer being restored before the login screen is loaded. I wouldn't be too concerned unless you keep sensitive things on your screen when you hibernate. An easy thing to do would be to minimize all windows before hibernate.

I doubt you will be able to interact with any of the items before the login screen pops up as these items are in the graphics buffer and not in the running memory.

Comment: That seems like a very plausible answer, I'll hold on accepting it for now to give others a chance just in case anything else is suggested.